# PL/pgSQL: Why I get a 'set-returning functions' message error?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I’m discovering PL/ pgSQL and the functions creation. In order to create a code more human readable I would like use custom nested functions or in other words I want call a function with the results of one other. My functions are:

```
  CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS routing_roaddata_func;
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "routing_roaddata_func".get_nav_strand_ids(link_id_v bigint ) RETURNS TABLE 
  (nav_strand_ids bigint) as $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY select nav_strand_id from rdf_wvd_211f0_1.rdf_nav_strand  where link_id = link_id_v ;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  
  --------------
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "routing_roaddata_func".get_condition_type(strand_ids_v bigint) RETURNS TABLE
  (condition_id_ bigint )
  AS $$
  BEGIN
  condition_id_ := (select condition_type from rdf_wvd_211f0_1.rdf_condition  where nav_strand_id = strand_ids_v );
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  
  ---------------
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "routing_roaddata_func".get_condition_type2(strand_ids_v bigint, out condition_id_ bigint)
  AS $$
  BEGIN
  condition_id_ := (select condition_type from rdf_wvd_211f0_1.rdf_condition  where nav_strand_id = strand_ids_v );
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  
  ----------------
```

And I get some troubles when I want use its.
I try :

```
select "routing_roaddata_func".get_nav_strand_ids(820636761); -- works
select "routing_roaddata_func".get_condition_type("routing_roaddata_func".get_nav_strand_ids(820636761)); -- the returns is empty

select "routing_roaddata_func".get_condition_type2("routing_roaddata_func".get_nav_strand_ids(820636761)); -- works
  
select * from "routing_roaddata_func".get_condition_type("routing_roaddata_func".get_nav_strand_ids(820636761)); **--ERROR:  set-returning functions must appear at top level of FROM**
```

It's annoying because my final goal is to add a where clause like that to detect the presence of one modality in the returned values.

```
select * from "routing_roaddata_func".get_condition_type("routing_roaddata_func".get_nav_strand_ids(820636761)) where condition_type = 23;
```

Someone could explain me the problem of the "set-returning functions" ? How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

Set Returning Function (in Postgres terminology - function that returns table) cannot be used as argument of any other function. You can pass more values as one parameter using by an arrays, or you can use `LATERAL` join:

```
create or replace function fx(int[])
returns table (a int, b int) as $$
begin
  for i in 1..3 loop
    foreach b in array $1 loop
      a := i; return next;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- ARRAY(subselect) does an array from table
postgres=# select * from fx(array(select generate_series(1,3)));
┌───┬───┐
│ a │ b │
╞═══╪═══╡
│ 1 │ 1 │
│ 1 │ 2 │
│ 1 │ 3 │
│ 2 │ 1 │
│ 2 │ 2 │
│ 2 │ 3 │
│ 3 │ 1 │
│ 3 │ 2 │
│ 3 │ 3 │
└───┴───┘
(9 rows)

-- using LATERAL join
create or replace function fx1(int)
returns table (a int, b int) as $$
begin
  for i in 1..3 loop
     a := i; b := $1; return next;            
  end loop;  
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

-- for any row of function generate_series is called function fx1
postgres=# select fx1.*
              from generate_series(1,3) g(v),
                   LATERAL fx1(v) order by a, b;
┌───┬───┐
│ a │ b │
╞═══╪═══╡
│ 1 │ 1 │
│ 1 │ 2 │
│ 1 │ 3 │
│ 2 │ 1 │
│ 2 │ 2 │
│ 2 │ 3 │
│ 3 │ 1 │
│ 3 │ 2 │
│ 3 │ 3 │
└───┴───┘
(9 rows)
```